# QVector or list of custom type(s) from C++ to QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qt5.15

After days of experimenting I surrender returning a list of custom objects to QML. I don't want to use QVariantList or any list creating a QVariant, as I'd like to preserve the custom objects structure and also allow using the signals from it (CItem).

CTest.h

```cpp
class CTest : public QObject
...
Q_INVOKABLE QVector<CItemWrapper> getAllItems();
```

CTest.cpp

```
QVector<CItemWrapper> CTest::getAllItems(){ // tried std::vecotor, QList, ...
  return {CItemWraper(...)};
};
```

CItemWrapper.h

```
class CItemWrapper: public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(QString title READ getTitle WRITE setTitle NOTIFY titleChanged)
  Q_PROPERTY(CItem * item READ getSignal WRITE setSignal NOTIFY signalChanged)
...
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(CItemWrapper)
```

CItem.h

```
class CEntry : public QObject{
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY( EValueStatus status READ getStatus NOTIFY statusChanged )
  Q_PROPERTY( QString displayValue READ getDisplayValue NOTIFY displayValueChanged )
...
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE( CItem )
```

main.cpp

```cpp
qmlRegisterType<CItem>( "Test", 1, 0, "CItem" );
qmlRegisterType<CItemWrapper>( "Test", 1, 0, "WrappedItem" );
std::unique_ptr<CTest> test = std::make_unique<CTest>( *wrappedItems );
view->rootContext()->setContextProperty( "TEST", test.get() );
```

main.qml

```css
import Test 1.0
Repeater{
  model: TEST.getAllItems()
  delegate: Text{
    text: modelData.title + " " + modelData.item.status
  }
}
```

Will result in `ERROR: Unknown method return type QVector<CWrappedItems>` and I couldn't find any way to overcome this. Consulting the QT online help I feel like that I'm doing anything needed to register a type to the QT system.

Do you have any hints?

Comment: Did you try with a pointer to `CWrappedItems` ?

Comment: do you mean `QVector<CItemWrapper*>  CTest::getAllItems()`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, not sure of the reason but for QList that's often what required. Also, CItemWrapper should derive from QObject, does it?

Comment: OK. Yes `CItemWrapper` is a child of QObject. Unfortunately, the trick with the pointer didn't help. Same message but with updated return type.. Thanks anyway, appreciate it!

Comment: You've registered the type `CItemWrapper`, but maybe you also need to do it for `QVector<CItemWrapper*>`?

Comment: @JarMan thank your for another hint. Tried it, but once I do so I got `C:\Qt\5.15.0\mingw81_64\include\QtQml\qqmlprivate.h:71: error: 'staticMetaObject' is not a member of 'CItemWrapper*'` . So I cannot compile. The message confuses me as I thought it can be resolved by creating a copy constructor within `CItemWrapper` but unfortunately that's not the case.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to access item elements from a list into QML. Have you looked at inheriting [QAbstractListModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html) for `CItemWrapper` and using role names to access the fields? This is considered the straight forward approach.

Comment: Hi @slayer, thanks for another hint. Yes I did, it is an option indeed. But also here you'll need to define the data function to deliver the element from within the model based on given role. The return type of data is QVariant, which will again screw up your object.. It's another approach I agree, but it is not exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @Nico As long as your object inherits from QObject you can cast it as a QVariant type. But in your example you are accessing the individual member variables `title` and `status` so you don't need to send your entire wrapper object. So you can use the rolenames and subclass QAbstractListModel